# How to drop connection after each WCF service request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, load-balancing, wshttpbinding

I have cluster of servers with identical WCF service. On top of that I have loadbalancer. Unfortunately for scenario when one client sends hundreds of requests only one service gets handle its.
From Loadbalancer perspective client and service establish one connection client ip:port <-> server ip:port 
And Loadbalancer based on it do not change traffic, the request are transparent for LB, it is operates on number of connections.

How to make client that for each request will establish new connection (new ip:port)?
I tried close connection on server (receiveTime="00:00:01").
I close channel on client side (channel.Close(), chanhel.Abort()). But so far all stays the same.

Comment: You should really reconfigure your LB instead. Use round robin or something other than sticky session.

Comment: This has been already answered https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190688/wcf-keep-alive-whether-to-disable-keepaliveenabled

Comment: @metase this has nothing to do with the LB, is related to WCF bindings